# Meteor, prerender.io, Nginx and SSL

Tags: ssl, meteor, nginx, prerender

I'm trying to get prerender.io working for my Meteor app with the Nginx configuration, but not sure exactly how to integrate it.

I've done something similar to the following:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-setup-prerender-io-on-my-mean-stack-application-running-behind-nginx

By putting the http proxy stuff in the section:

```
if ($prerender = 0) {
    #the directives
}
```

But have the issue of:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_http_version" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/annachristoffer:48
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to find a source online that explains it.

Comment: I got it working finally not using nginx with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967599/unable-to-setup-ssl-with-nginx-prerender-meteor
but would still like to know how to do it with nginx

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the `proxy_http_version` directive is not allowed to be used inside an `if` block. The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) specifies a *context* for each directive. For example, the `proxy_pass` directive *is* allowed to be used inside an `if` block.

Many of `nginx` directives can be inherited from an outer block, so it may be possible for you to restructure your configuration like this:

```
proxy_http_version ...;
proxy_... ...;

if ($prerender = 0) {
    ...;
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

Please be aware that the use of `if` [comes with a caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).